# Typings for multiple graphql query imports via graphql-tag/loader

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo, graphql-tag

I have a component which imports a query from a graphql file via the graphql-tag/loader of webpack.

```
query testQuery {
  test
}

query test2Query {
   test
}
```

```js
import { testQuery, test2Query } from './test.graphql'
```

I'm now trying to declare a general typing for all possible queries and mutations:

```
declare module '*.graphql' {
  import { DocumentNode } from 'graphql';
  const exp: { [key: string]: DocumentNode };

  export default exp;
}
```

The typescript compiler doesn't recognize my import. I know my typing definition is faulty, though I can't seem to find documentation which would help me in this case.

Any suggestions?

Comment: https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tag#typescript-preprocessing ?

Comment: That is, unfortunately, the opposite of what I want to do. I have the queries and mutations in a separate file and not as a stringed template literal

Comment: https://github.com/dotansimha/graphql-code-generator ?